# Referencia no mongodb

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, react, react-native, mongoose

Bom galera, sei que o mongo não existe relacionamentos, mais preciso saber como faço algo relacionado.
Tenho duas coleçẽos uma chamada, Extintor e a outra Historico, quero um extinto tem uma lista do seu histórico, alguem poderia me ajudar, como faria isso, mongoose node, react-native.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, diferentemente dos Bancos Relacionais, no SGBD MongoDB não existe o conceito de relacionamento e sim, de referência.

No seu contexto, você pode embarcar os documentos contidos na coleção **extintor** com um array **histórico**.

Mas caso queira ter duas coleções, você pode:

Na coleção Histórico, referenciar a coleção Extintor. Dessa forma, eles estarão relacionados pelo Object ID (chave primária) gerada pelo próprio, MongoDB;

*Não sei exatamente como trabalha o Mongoose Node, mas deixo este link na intenção de ajudar:*

[Link Para Referência](https://nodejs.docow.com/2738/mongoose-objectid-que-faz-referencia-a-um-sub-documento.html)

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Vlw amigo, salvo minha vida!